# How to display a layout on top of other layout in android

Tags: android

Below is my image.[image]

Pagerlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"

android:layout_weight="1"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@color/bean_green"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


    <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >

                    <Button
                        android:text="BUTTON"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
                    />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Text 1"
                        android:paddingTop="10px"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Text 2"
                        android:paddingTop="10px"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Text 3"
                        android:paddingTop="10px"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
















    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

In the above layout at the top tabs bar, I have a button. When I click on the button the layout with text views should extend and display below the button. But currently, the linear layout is showing on click of the button, but the view pager is going down. Instead, it should display on the view pager screen overlapping it, like how we drag any notifications in android in which it hides the back screen. Can anybody please suggest me on this. Thank you

Comment: Please fix the sentence "But currently, the when the linear layout is showing on click of a button but the viewpager is going down." so that someone can understand what you mean.

Comment: Also, when you say "on top of", do you mean "above" or "in front of"?

Comment: Hi sorry..i changed the sentence. Can  you please check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read your Code and i try it.i think you try when you click on button visible layout on top but viewpager not going down. 
try this code :

in this code when you click on button linear layout is visible on top of another layout like notification

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLinearlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Total"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
       >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BUTTON" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10px"
            android:text="Text 1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10px"
            android:text="Text 2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10px"
            android:text="Text 3" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>





 </RelativeLayout>
```

i hope it helps you